# breaking if statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to break the if statement.

My code is like this:

```
if a == 0 or d == 0:
    while a>0:
        d=a//b
        c+=1
        a=d//b
        c+=1
    break
```

I got an error called `'break' outside loop` what can I do.

Comment: The `break` keyword is used to exit a loop, not a conditional statement, so the interpreter doesn't know what you'd want to do with this code.

Comment: What exactly did you expect that break to do that does not happen if you just remove it?

Comment: .... just don't do anything inside the If block?  If you don't want anything to do with the If statement then just move to another block?

Comment: I think you need to re-state what you want the code to do. Try giving us some example input values for a,b,c,d and an expected result.

Comment: It is unclear from the code in the question what you are trying to accomplish. A `break` statement where you've placed one does not make conceptual sense, nor does it appear to be intended to have any actual effect (i.e. even something like you appear to want would have no actual effect in that location). Please [edit] your question to make it more clear as to what you are really wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question indicates that you have bad design somewhere, but here is a reasonable (not good, more of "least bad") way of "breaking out of an if statement":

```
class IfBreaker(Exception):
    pass

a=1
b=2 # Change to see the difference

try:
    if(a==1):
        if(b==1):
            raise IfBreaker
        print("Will not be printed if b==1")
except IfBreaker:
    pass
```

But in general, you break out of loops. Not if statements. If you find that you need to to that, it's very likely that you have done something very wrong. The above approach is good if the breaking is because some kind of error that you want to throw an exception for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "break" an if statement. You can "break" the while loop though. You can add an "if" statement inside the while loop to break it

Comment: I want to break the if condition.

Comment: You're pretty much just repeating what OP stated in the question

Comment: You can't break the if condition. You can change the condition itself, but once it evaluates to true, you can't break it

Comment: So that I am asking to break it I know that I can break the loops only. Read the question carefully

Comment: You know that you can only break out of a loop, so you're asking how to break out of things that aren't loops?

Comment: Well, you can't do what you want in this way. You need to change other parts of the code

Comment: @Daniel I can change

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes.

Comment: You _can't_ break out of things that aren't loops. It already told you that.